# Magento $this->_productCollection how to rearrange using foreach

Tags: php, magento

i am very new to magento please look at the code below i am trying to rearrange productCollection on different basis.

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();   
$rearraggedProductCollection=array();

foreach($this->_productCollection as $product)
{

  if($product->getTypeId()=="simple")
  {   
     array_push($rearraggedProductCollection,$product); 
  }

 }
$this->_productCollection = $rearraggedProductCollection;
```

But this is not working , anyone help will be appreciated.

Comment: You got error? If yes what is it?

Comment: no i don't get any error , i think there is a type mismatch between array and object type, i am confused  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou everyone for helping me out with this problem.

I have found the soloution , its simple and there is a addItem() which can easily help to add a new product to the _productCollection object.

I only trick is to load a empty collection

```
//load an empty collection (filter-less collections will auto-lazy-load everything)
$merged = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',-1);
```

and while adding product to the empty table we need to be shure to check the product id don't duplicate , magento don't allow to add duplicate product to the product collection

```
if(!$merged->getItemById($product->getId())) 
{
  $merged->addItem($product);
}
```

The entire code is below as per my requirements

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

//load an empty collection (filter-less collections will auto-lazy-load everything)
$merged = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',-1);


                /**** Sorting the backorder product first ****/
                foreach($this->_productCollection as $product)
                {
                   if($product->getTypeId()=="simple" && $product->isSaleable())
                    {
                       if(!$merged->getItemById($product->getId())) 
                        {
                            $merged->addItem($product);
                        }        
                    }
                }

                /**** Sorting the avilable product second ****/
                foreach($this->_productCollection as $product)
                {
                   if($product->getTypeId()=="configurable" && $product->isSaleable())
                    {
                       if(!$merged->getItemById($product->getId())) 
                        {
                            $merged->addItem($product);
                        }        
                    }
                }

                 /**** Sorting the sold out product last ****/
                foreach($this->_productCollection as $product)
                {
                   if(!$product->isSaleable())
                    {
                       if(!$merged->getItemById($product->getId())) 
                        {
                            $merged->addItem($product);
                        }        
                    }
                } 

                /* Now assigning to the mergerd collection to the product Collection */
                $this->_productCollection = $merged;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just apply a filter to the collection?

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
```

Comment: Actually i don't want to filter product i want to sort it but there are many condition on which i want to sort like as per my requirement  first product catalog will show backorder products first >> then available >> after that sold out products . for this reason i am picking up product and keeping it in a array.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [PHP Clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

```
foreach($this->_productCollection as $product) {

    if($product->getTypeId()=="simple") {   
        array_push($rearraggedProductCollection, clone $product); 
    }

}
```

I am suspect of the following statement, I am not sure you can reset an object like that.

```
$this->_productCollection = $rearraggedProductCollection;
```

Can you confirm that your array is being set correctly, treating objects like arrays can cause some funky behaviour.

[var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump) each stage and try pin point where it is going wrong